# Average Certain Number Of Elements in List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm thinking that I could do this in LINQ but I'm new to it so I was hoping someone could help me out some.  I have a list (I believe it is a list) that I generated using this code:

```
var dividendsList = from div in context.DividendsEntitySet
                    where div.CUSIP.Equals(cusip)
                    orderby div.PayableDate descending
                    select div;
```

The `dividendsList` contains `Dividend` objects.  Each dividend object has a property called `rate`.  My goal is to average a varying number of these `rates`.  So, for example, at one point I might want to average first 12 rates.

Now I know that I could just loop through the list but I was wondering if there was a quicker/more efficient way of doing this because I'm going to be executing this numerous times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use Fluent and just do something like:

```
dividendsList.Take(10).Average(m => m.rate)
```

That will take the first 10 items from the list, and average their `rate` properties together.